# Compiling of ML Kit model on demand

Tags: ios, tensorflow, coreml, google-mlkit

I want to check if it is possible to use [ML Kit Pose Detection](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/pose-detection/ios) without having it in the initial application bundle (to reduce application size).

I am looking for functionality similar to one provided by Core ML with [Downloading and Compiling a Model on the User’s Device](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreml/downloading_and_compiling_a_model_on_the_user_s_device). For now, as an option, I found it possible by using [Tensor Flow](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/coreml_delegate#swift) with converted to `.tflite` model, but still curious about any possible ways to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use VNDetectHumanBodyPoseRequest, it's integrated in iOS SDK.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/detecting_human_body_poses_in_images